# Release C# builds much larger with VS 2017

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I've noticed that release exes for VS 2017 C# projects built with msbuild are about 30% larger than previous builds for VS 2015 (the source code is identical for both cases).

Is this normal or is there some new switch in project properties that I'm missing?

Comment: Since the assemblies are emitted by the compiler, so you can report Roslyn repo, https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen

Comment: @LexLi: Thanks, but I'm more interested in knowing if this is normal or if there's a reason or tradeoff for this - e.g., faster loading of the assembly?